# How do I get JSON from HTTPS links in Perl?

Tags: json, perl, https

I have found many examples of Perl and JSON that helped me understand it better.

The code provided in an answer to *[Simple JSON parsing using Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210523/simple-json-parsing-perl)* was good and is used below in the example of my issue.

I am having trouble 'get'-ing JSON from HTTPS links, and I am not sure why.

The above example code works for me if I use:

```
"http:..."
```

as the `$trendsurl`, but it fails on the die line (adding `$`!), with

> 'Could not get https:... - **No such file or directory**  at
>   json-simple.pl line 23.'

if I use

```
"https:..."
```

Why does `https` fail, and how do I get it working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install `LWP:Protocol:https` to make an HTTPS request work. If you are using Ubuntu then you also need `build-essential libssl-dev`. Once done, you should be able to make HTTPS requests.

Here is a snippet to call Twitter via HTTPS..

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

 use LWP::UserAgent;
 use HTTP::Request;

 my $URL = 'https://www.twitter.com/';

 my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 1 });
 my $header = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $URL);
 my $request = HTTP::Request->new('GET', $URL, $header);
 my $response = $ua->request($request);

 if ($response->is_success){
     print "URL:$URL\nHeaders:\n";
     print $response->headers_as_string;
 }elsif ($response->is_error){
     print "Error:$URL\n";
     print $response->error_as_HTML;
 }
```

Comment: No don't use useragent  for restful it will activate  keep alive and your connection  will not close  to 3 min.