# How to access JSON data from perl?

Tags: json, perl, data-structures

I have a JSON file as below.

```
{
    "card":{
      "cardName":"10AN10G",
      "portSignalRates":[
         "10AN10G-1-OTU2",
         "10AN10G-1-OTU2E",
         "10AN10G-1-TENGIGE",
         "10AN10G-1-STM64"
      ],
      "listOfPort":{
         "10AN10G-1-OTU2":{
            "portAid":"10AN10G-1-OTU2",
            "signalType":"OTU2",
            "tabNames":[
               "PortDetails"
            ],
            "requestType":{
               "PortDetails":"PTP"
            },
            "paramDetailsMap":{
               "PortDetails":[
                  {
                     "type":"dijit.form.TextBox",
                     "name":"signalType",
                     "title":"Signal Rate",
                     "id":"",
                     "options":[

                     ],
                     "label":"",
                     "value":"OTU2",
                     "checked":"",
                     "enabled":"false",
                     "selected":""
                  },
                  {
                     "type":"dijit.form.TextBox",
                     "name":"userLabel",
                     "title":"Description",
                     "id":"",
                     "options":[

                     ],
                     "label":"",
                     "value":"",
                     "checked":"",
                     "enabled":"true",
                     "selected":""
                  },
                  {
                     "type":"dijit.form.Select",
                     "name":"Frequency",
                     "title":"Transmit Frequency"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I require the output to be:

```
signalType:"Signal Rate",
userLabel:"Description",
Frequency:"Transmit Frequency",.. ,.....
```

I tried with:

```
grep -oP '(?<=\"title\":\")[^"]*' file > outfile
```

but this just splits the value of title and returns.

Can I use perl to access elements of the JSON data that I want?

Comment: Is JSON::Parse out of the question?

Comment: I don't think this is the problem but, just to let you know, your JSON you posted is invalid.

Comment: `jq` is a nifty command line filter for json of the sed/awk sort. http://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: I edited the post to make the JSON "valid". I used an online service and `jq`, `json_verify` to check the work.  My thinking was a basic question like this might be useful to answer (even repeatedly), but that it needed proper data to be useful. I would not be surprised if it was a duplicate of another SO post ([*e.g.* see this one on JSON and perl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5210523/2019415)). But I think that is OK :-)

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to use `decode_json` instead of a regex. First, install the JSON module from CPAN:

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install JSON'
```

Alternatively you can use `apt-get` on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libjson-pp-perl
```

Once it is installed, you can use this code:

```
my $json = '{... your json string ...}';
my $decoded = decode_json($json);

$decoded->{'card'}{'listOfPort'}{'10AN10G-1-OTU2'}{'signalType'}
```

You can find more details in [this](http://xmodulo.com/2013/04/how-to-parse-json-string-in-perl.html) article.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use the [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) perl module. Of course it meeds to be installed via `cpan`, `cpanm` or your system's packaging system. Parse the JSON into a hash and then use that in the normal way from Perl. Here's a quick example:

```
use JSON;
use IO::All;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data < io '/tmp/data.json';
my $j = decode_json($data);

use DDP; # for quick debug printing

p $j->{card}{listOfPort}{"10AN10G-1-OTU2"}{paramDetailsMap}{PortDetails}[0]{title}
"Signal Rate"
```

You might want to use some deep diving techniques to get at the inner values more easily/programmatically (take a look at the [`Data::Diver`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Diver) module for that) -  my example is meant to show only that it is possible and a bit of the mechanics of mapping JSON into a `perl` hash with the excellent JSON module. The documentation has lots of useful examples.

Answer (score 0):

Perl on the command line:

```
perl -pe 's/"name":"([^"]+)","title":/"$1":/g' file > outfile
```

Output (pertinent part):

```
{"card": ... "signalType":"Signal Rate", ... "userLabel":"Description", ... "Frequency":"Transmit Frequency" ... }
```

Comment: Ah, okay. Updated response to execute with Perl on the command line.